# Conditional htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a rewrite rule to redirect to a URL based on a conidtion.

I have had a look on-line for similar questions but am finding myself confused.

My rewrite rule looks like follows:

```
RewriteRule ^rates/(\w+)/?$ http://www.url.co.uk/rates/result.php?quotenum=$1 [R,L]
```

For example, this will redirect any combination of characters after the URL

```
www.url.co.uk/rates/1234
```

to

```
www.url.co.uk/rates/result.php?quotenum=1234
```

I am creating an admin page as well which will sit at the URL:

```
www.url.co.uk/rates/admin
```

How do I modify my rewrite rule to prevent the redirection of the URL to

```
www.url.co.uk/rates/result.php?quotenum=admin
```

When the URL is equal to

```
www.url.co.uk/rates/admin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^rates/((?!admin/?$)\w+)/?$ http://www.url.co.uk/rates/result.php?quotenum=$1 [R,L,NC]
```

`(?!admin/?$)` is a **negative lookahead** that will not match given regex if URI is `/rates/admin` OR `/rates/admin`